# casting & generics to enable list concatenation in Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Apologies that is probably the worst Title I've used but I can't quite think how to word it.

I'm calling a method table.getColData(COL_1) which returns a generic

```
public <T extends Object> List<T> getColData(final String col)
```

I am calling it twice and getting two lists of strings.  I want to concatenate these and have ended up with this -

```
List<String> a = table.getColData(col1);
List<String> b = table.getColData(col2);

List <String> c = Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which works nicely I think. I can't find a way to avoid the 2 declarations though without getting an error as the `concat` thinks it has a list of objects that are not `String`s (prompt: change type of `c` to `List<Object>`) ?

Is there an easy way to do this to make it look a little more polished?!

Comment: well `T extends Object` makes no sense to begin with

Comment: Wouldn't this work? `List<String> c = table.getColData(col1); c.addAll(table.getColData(col2));`

Comment: @Holger You concat Lists here and not streams and even with streams i don't think that it will compile because  the `table.getColData(col2)`  return is inferred to `Object`

Comment: just interested now,  what does `getColData` return?

Comment: @davidxxx ok, `Stream.concat(table.<String>getColData(col1).stream(), table.<String>getColData(col2).stream())` then.

Comment: @Holger It is a very clean way.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I thought that but it is inherited code and wondered if I was missing something.

Comment: Sorry @Eugene to answer your question intellisense says the return object is <String> List <String> but I'm guess (as per Davidxxx's answer) this is not quite what is being inferred by the compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are limited by the inference of the compiler.

```
List <String> c = Stream.concat(getColDataStream(col1).stream(), getColDataStream(col2).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

cannot compile because `getColDataStream()` return is inferred as `List<Object>` as you don't specify a target type from the invocation side.
You can concatenate two streams of `List<Object>` but it not will produce  `Stream<String>` but `Stream<Object>`.
Introducing two intermediary variables is not necessary the best way.

1) As alternative as suggested by Holger you could specify the `T` type from the target side :

```
 Stream.concat(table.<String>getColData(col1).stream(), table.<String>getColData(col2).stream()) 
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2) You could also transform `Stream<Object>` to `Stream<String>`in a `map()` operation :

```
List<String> c = Stream.concat(table.getColData(col1).stream(), table.getColData(col2).stream())
                           .map(s -> (String) s)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

3) or introducing an additional method that prevents any explicit cast by concatenating streams of the lists, and collecting it in a `List` that it returns :

```
public <T> List<T> concatAndCollectToList(final List<T> a, List<T> b) {
    return Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream())
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can now do just :

```
List<String> c = concatAndCollectToList(table.getColData(col1), table.getColData(col2));
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I think 1 was what I was intending to ask and so I've marked this as the answer (also as it is so complete!) but 2 (combined with Nikolas's answer further down is where I would like to be!).

Comment: @gringogordo You are very welcome. Fine ! I think that no solution is really better than others. It is more a taste question.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I would add a type witness (a method argument) that is not used, to make this method type safe:

```
public static <T> List<T> getColData(String col, Class<T> clazz) {
     // whatever you did as before
}
```

And in such a case your type-safety would be in place:

```
List<String> set = Stream.concat(
                     getColData("", String.class).stream(),
                     getColData("", String.class).stream())
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I thought *type witness* usually means `<String>getColData(...)`. Is a class parameter like this also called *type witness*?

Comment: @kapex I have no idea about the absolute correct name for this... sorry :| I call it type witness, but might have some other official name

Comment: @kapex and btw its called *type witness* in the oracle tutorials, but *type arguments* in the `JLS`

Comment: This is a solid solution. Because of runtime type erasure providing at run-time the class is best. 1. **inside** `getColData` one might add to the resulting list objects casted: `list.add(clazz.cast(resultSet.getObject(col)));` 2. outside it is entirely type-safe.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `T extends Object` is redundant since every object `T` extends from `Object` since the definition.

Since the method returns `List<T>`, it's unknown at the compilation time what type is `T`, therefore it's not possible to pass those two generic results to `Stream` - the collected result is `List<Object>` regardless the `T`.

You have to map each of the values to `String` - at this point you have to assure that all the list items are convertible into `String` using casting or conversion:

```
List<String> c = Stream
                 .concat(table.getColData(col1).stream(), table.getColData(col2).stream())
                 .map(s -> (String) s)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I recommend you the shorter and more readable way which uses `Stream::flatMap`:

```
List<String> c = Stream.of(table.getColData(col1), table.getColData(col2))
                       .flatMap(list -> list.stream().map(s -> (String) s))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result depends on what exactly the method `getColData` returns and whether it is convertible to `String` (@Eugene).

Comment: what do you that method *can* return under the current declaration?

Comment: @Eugene: What do you mean? I don't understand your question :(

Comment: `public static <T> List<T> getColData(String col) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(1);
        return (List<T>) l;
    }` as an example of the method (otherwise the only thing you can return would be `List.of()` or `Collections.emptyList()` or `null`)  and later do `List<String> l = getColData("");
        System.out.println(l.get(0).length());` which will break at runtime, of course

Comment: The compiler will infer whatever target type is provided, like in the question’s `List<String> a = table.getColData(col1);`. So you can write `Stream.<List<String>>of( table.getColData(col1), table.getColData(col2)) .flatMap(List::stream) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Holger which sucks to me, that type parameter is not used as a method argument, thus you can basically return whatever List you want with a cast to `List<T>`

Comment: @Eugene sure, the compiler can’t check what actual type the column will have at runtime, so this construct is undermining the type safety. But that’s the design issue of the `getColData` method, not of the subsequent stream operation.

Comment: @Holger right, and this IIRC has nothing to do with stream per-se, *any* chaining would cause that

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, you are right. I have added a note about that. Of course the suitable mapping should be used (`String::valueOf` etc...).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest would be:

```
Stream.of(col1, col2)
      .map(table::<String>getColData)
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Since your `getColData` method returns a `T`, you can specify what type `T` is by using a [type witness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) `<String>`. The rest is the java syntax for [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Also, the use of generics can be questioned here. This is equivalent to having

```
public List<Object> getColData(final String col)
```

and casting your list to a list of `String`:

```
Stream.of(col1, col2)
      .map(table::getColData)
      .map(o -> (String) o)
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Some description why `table::<String>getColDat` and how does it work would not hurt ;)

Comment: Yes, I just updated my answer to include some details about that!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to just add a generic argument to the method using `<>`

```
Stream.concat(
        table.<String>getColData(col1).stream(),
        table.<String>getColData(col2).stream())
    .collect(toList());
```